# how do i force a tempdata to show up after the action returns from a jquery call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I call this action using jquery

```
public ActionResult Delete(int Id){
   Schedule schedule = context.Schedules.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == Id);
   try{
       context.Schedules.Remove(schedule);
       context.SaveChanges();
       TempData["Message"] = "Succesfully removed schedule.";
       return Content(Boolean.TrueString);
   }catch(Exception ex){
       TempData["Message"] = "Something went wrong";
       return Content(Boolean.FalseString);
   }

}
```

On my view I have a div that handles the TempData["Message"] from the master

```
<div id="messages">
 <% if(ViewContext.TempData["Message"] != null { %>
     <div class="alert">
        <%: ViewContext.TempData["Message"] %>
     </div>
  <% } %>
</div>
```

this is exactly how my jquery looks like. using the Boolean.TrueString / FalseString return. I'm not really sure if that's the right way, as I'm still starting to learn jquery with actions.

http://ricardocovo.com/2010/09/02/asp-mvc-delete-confirmation-with-ajax-jquery-ui-dialog/

Basically my goal is to be able to show any errors, or notify the users of anything that is wrong or any instructions that needs to be done to finish the steps. Was thinking of maybe just using JSON as the return type? I'm not really sure how to handle it.

any recommendations is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using an ajax call; the View won't get fully rendered again; to be able to show a message you'll have to return it as json for example and handle it in the jquery callback.

Comment: so im trying to delete  row, and i want to automatically hide the div just like in the example. how do i handle the json return after deleting?

Comment: to be able to return JSon, you should change the return type of the Delete method to JsonResult, then you can do something like: "return Json(new {success = true, message = "all went well"})". You'll also have to adapt the callback at client side to handle what you have returned from server side appropriately.

Comment: awesome, i was able to make this work. was wondering if i can edit your comment to update the code?? im picking this as the answer..

Comment: feel free to put in a comment here, then I'll put it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ViewData instead of TempData in this scenario.
TempData is used to temporary store something between requests. And it uses Session object behind the scene. Like in Post->Redirect->Get .

In your case you use data in the same request. So TempData is not needed.

Comment: isn't tempdatabetter cuz it goes away after?

Answer (score 0):

When you calling this function with jQuery, you are calling it async. This is done by AJAX and it's much easier to return the message in JSON:

```
Response.Write('{"message":"foo"}');
```

in jQuery you just have to call the dialog when the ajax-request is finished:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.aspx"
}).done(function(data) { 
  $(".alert").text(data.message);
  $("#messages").dialog();
});
```

Comment: so i'm trying to delete a row in a list. how do i check if the row was succesffully deleted and that i can hide the div already?

Comment: also, is the "data.message" getting the "message:foo" part? just asking as im planning to return something like this return Json(new {message=success});